# Display speed for SVG path

Tags: javascript, svg

Good Day;

I surely hope someone can help me with this.
The page is http://www.drdelmath.com/sketch_parabola/

The problem description is long in an attempt to avoid misunderstanding.

When you enter the page a parabola will be drawn on the right part of the screen.  Note the speed with which it is drawn.  That is what I want with everything to come on this page. (This blue parabola is only to demonstrate what I want)

I am doing all my drawing with SVG.

There are a number of items to be drawn on the page.
However, the user/student is to determine, by clicking on a button, when an item is displayed.  Two such buttons are included in this example.

All elements were drawn with visibility=hidden when you entered the page.
When the student clicks a button I use JavaScript to set visibility=visible for the desired item.  They are displayed.  However they are drawn much too fast.  Click the "Sketch the parabola" button and compare the speed to the speed when the blue parabola was drawn.

How can I slow down the displaying so that it looks like someone is drawing the item?

Or is there a way to delay execution of the SVG path statement until the student clicks the button? If this is possible then I can use visibility =visible and everything performs as desired.

Del

Comment: I think you should approach this by displaying elements within the SVG, via JavaScript.

Comment: The delay you speak about is being achieved via CSS. Did you try appending paths manually instead of toggling visibility?

Comment: Brad and Tanzeel;  I do not understand what you are suggesting.  How do I display elements within SVG ?  How do I append paths manually? What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is put the animation CSS properties in a class that the SVG `<path>` elements don't have initially.  Then when you add the class, the animation begins.

So, for example, change the definition of the "path" CSS rule as follows:

```
.path {
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
}

.showpath {
    animation: 5s linear 0s normal forwards 1 running dash;
}
```

and you can remove the "visibility: hidden" property if you want.

Then in your button handler, add the "showpath" class to the path you want to animate in.

```
document.getElementById("parabola").setAttribute("class", "path showpath");
```

There is a problem with your SVG however.  You have given the same "id" attribute to more than one element.  "id" attributes **must** to be unique.  So you should, for instance, call them "parabola1" and "parabola2".

```
document.getElementById("parabola1").setAttribute("class", "path showpath");
```

If you need to reset them to invisible, you can put the class attribute back to how it started.

```
document.getElementById("parabola1").setAttribute("class", "path");
```

Comment: Thanks BigBadaboom.  Your suggestions made me a happy man.  See http://www.drdelmath.com/sketch_parabola/index.html in FF at high resolution (I still have some work to make it behave at lower resolution).  HOWEVER, it only seems to work in FF and I think it is because most of the other browsers (especially IE) do not support SVG animate.  For lines I can acc

Comment: Should I look to JavaScript for a workaround? I know how to use JavaScript for the lines but not for the parabola.

Comment: For other browsers you will need to prefix the `animation` and `@keyframes` rules.  For example, in Chrome you need to use `-webkit-animation`.  See the Browser Compatibility table here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: I cannot get it to work in IE10 or IE11.  Seems to now (with prefixes) work in latest versions of FF, Opera, Chrome, Safari, on my Android phone.  but not IE.  Is there any hope of getting that to work?

Comment: The current working version is at http://www.drdelmath.com/sketch_parabola/index.html.

Comment: Sorry, IE (including 11) doesn't support CSS animation of SVG.  If you need it to work in IE, you will have to use JS to manipulate the stroke offset.  You could do it yourself, or use one of the SVG-manipulating JS libraries to help you.